# Python die roll

Tags: python-2.7

Working on this program and have this so far, any suggestions on how to get it to generate 1000 times randomly and incorporate a counter? This is as far as I have been able to get and I keep getting an error message with "if die = 1 counter =+1"

```
  *import random 
def rollDie(): 
die= random.randint(1,6) 
counter=0 
if die = (1) 
counter=+1 
if die=2 
counter=+1 
return die*
```

---

Comment: Your syntax is way off. I suggest you read through a few Python tutorials or pick up a decent book.

Comment: It's hard to tell how much of the problem here is your formatting and how much is your actual syntax, since indentation matters in Python. You you're missing colons after your `if` statements and you need `==` instead of `=` for comparisons at the very least, even if this were indented correctly.

Comment: Also, what are you using `counter` for? You're not counting anything, and you're not doing anything with it. (Even if you meant `counter += 1`, you still aren't counting since only one condition can be true...)

Comment: `from collections import Counter; from random import randint; Counter(randint(1, 6) for i in range(1000))`? :P

Comment: The basic code is supposed to simulate a die roll 1000 times and come back with a counter counting how many times it landed on 1 2 3 4 5 or 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison is `==`, assignment is  `=`. And don't forget the colon and correct indentation.

```
if die == 2:
    # do something useful
```

Answer (score 0):

## A easy code for die roll

```
import random

dieroll1 = random.randint(1,6)

print("You rolled a", dierolll)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if its the answer Nick wanted. As far as I can see, he needed some help with error...

Comment: I'm new member of stack overflow, so i'don't what to do?